# How to make Angular app aware of the day/date?

Tags: angularjs

I have a basic calendar/events listing app built in Angular.  I'm trying to only show the relevant events for the current day.  I'd like the view to adjust what it shows depending on the date.  What's the best way to bring in the current date and adjust the UI based on the date?

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-hide`, `ng-show` and a controller function. Assuming you pass an epoch timestamp to your controller function:

```
<div ng-contoller="MyCtrl">
    <p ng-show="isToday(date)">I'm visible today</p>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
    var today = new Date();
    today = today.getTime();
    today = $filter('date')(today, 'shortDate');

    $scope.isToday = function(epoch){
       return  $filter('date')(epoch, 'shortDate') == today;
    };
});
```